# How to select columns sharing common but unknown string elements using dplyr?

Tags: r, select, dplyr

Suppose I have data where I have count and percent columns based on some prior operations where the column names are data dependent. My question is how can I slect columns containing a common string when I dont' know the string in advance because its data dependent?
Some toy data where we do know the column names (but lets pretend we don't!)

```
library(tidyverse)

mtcars <- mtcars %>% 
    mutate(cnt_something = sample(0:100, nrow(mtcars)),
           cnt_otherthing = sample(0:100, nrow(mtcars)),
           pct_something = paste0( cnt_something, "%"),
           pct_otherthing = paste0( cnt_otherthing, "%"))
```

So in real data the strings `something` and `otherthing` result from previous data dependent steps and actually there could be many columns, but I know there will alway be a pair of columns in the form `cnt_` and `pct_`. My question is therefore how can I select the `cnt_*****` and `pct_****` with matching *****'s for the next manipulation (e.g. `paste0()`) without knowing the different possible ***** strings.

The desired output is something like this:

```
                   result_something result_otherthing
Mazda RX4                   49 (49%)          82 (82%)
Mazda RX4 Wag               20 (20%)          72 (72%)
Datsun 710                  37 (37%)          75 (75%)
Hornet 4 Drive              22 (22%)          85 (85%)
Hornet Sportabout           53 (53%)        100 (100%)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a series of pivots to transform this data:

```r
mtcars |>
  rownames_to_column("car") |>
  pivot_longer(matches("^(cnt|pct)"), names_sep = "_", names_to = c(".value", "grp")) |>
  mutate(x = str_glue("{cnt} ({pct})")) |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = grp, names_prefix = "result_", values_from = x, id_cols = car) |>
  column_to_rownames("car")
```

Note: in the tidyverse [row names are discouraged](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/vectors-chap.html#rownames), but since your example had them I used `rownames_to_column` and `column_to_rownames` from the `tibble` package to preserve them. This might not be necessary in your actual data.

Comment: Thanks actually exactly what I needed - thanks. My ral data does not have row names this was just a quick example I threw together thanks

Comment: You're welcome -- if that is the case then you can remove the `rownames_to_column` and `column_to_rownames` from the pipe chain to make it even more succinct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way, using rlang to parse constructed expressions

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rlang)

mtcars <- mtcars |> select() |>  
  mutate(cnt_something = sample(0:100, nrow(mtcars)),
         cnt_otherthing = sample(0:100, nrow(mtcars)),
         pct_something = paste0( cnt_something, "%"),
         pct_otherthing = paste0( cnt_otherthing, "%"))


funky_funks <- function(data,
         prefix_1,
         prefix_2,
         prefix_res){
nm1 <- names(mtcars)
(nm2 <- nm1[startsWith(nm1,prefix_1)])
(res_names <- str_replace(nm2,fixed(prefix_1),prefix_res))

plist <- map(nm2,\(n1){
    n2 <- str_replace(n1,prefix_1,prefix_2)
    myexpr <- paste0('paste0(',n1,'," (",',n2,',")")')
   rlang::parse_expr(myexpr)
}) |> set_names(res_names)

data |> mutate(!!!plist)
}


funky_funks(mtcars,
            prefix_1 = "cnt_",
            prefix_2 = "pct_",
            prefix_res = "result_")
```

Comment: Wow thanks. I don't understand this immediately but I'll take it apart to learn. I had been thinking along the lines of `dplyr::select(ends_with(***))` but could not figure out how to feed a data dependent vector into it.

Comment: A question, in the defintiion of `plist` - what does `\` do in `\(n1)` ? I'm not familiar with that syntax

Comment: its unclear what you are asking about, it seems the code formating in your comment is broken ? It occurs to me you may be asking about R's snytax for anonymous functions ; your original post question uses magrittr pipe `%>%` rather than the native pipe `|>` which was introduced in R4.1. you could read https://towardsdatascience.com/the-new-pipe-and-anonymous-function-syntax-in-r-54d98861014c